# set Content of a TinyMCE textarea via HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

To set a content of a TinyMCE textarea we use this code in JavaScript :

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent('<strong>Some contents</strong>');
```

but how can I set the content via html, without JavaScript ?? I tried to use

```
<textarea>Some Contents</textarea>
```

but this is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define TinyMCE like that:

```
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
```

that code should do what you need:

```
<textarea>Some Contents</textarea>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/n9djp4u2/

Comment: That's great. for specific TinyMCE textarea can I use :
`tinymce.init({selector:'#myid'});`

Comment: Exactly. But then make sure you have that id on textarea `<textarea id="myid"></textarea>`